# When to open and close brackets surrounding joins in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to understand when to open and close brackets when representing joins in MS Access queries as I am developing a query builder using C++ for MS Access queries so that I can apply the same code to generate similar queries.

```
SELECT 
    MasterTool.Name, Toolsets.SlaveToolID, Tools.MachineID  
FROM 
    Tools AS MasterTool
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        Toolsets LEFT JOIN Tools ON Toolsets.SlaveToolID = Tools.ID
    )
    ON MasterTool.ID = Toolsets.MasterToolID
```

**Edit:**

@LeeMac as per your explaination when i modified the query which i presented earlier to this

```
   SELECT Tools.Name, Toolsets.SlaveToolID, Tools.MachineID  FROM (Tools  
   LEFT JOIN  Toolsets ON Toolsets.SlaveToolID = Tools.ID )
   LEFT JOIN  Tools ON  Toolsets.MasterToolID = Tools.ID
```

i am getting error Join Expression Not Supported is there is any simple way to write the above query.

Comment: Generally, newcomers should build queries in MS Access GUI using the design viewer, then use the saved SQL where needed. In fact, because the Access engine saves and caches best execution plan, it is more efficient to used saved queries and not string run queries at application level (i.e., C++).

Comment: The SQL added in your edit is referencing the `Tools` table twice, therefore, the second reference will require an alias, e.g. `LEFT JOIN Tools t ON Toolsets.MasterToolID = t.ID`

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, when an MS Access query references more than two tables, every successive join between a pair of tables should be nested within parentheses.

For example, a query with two tables requires no parentheses:

[image]

```sql
select *
from a inner join b on a.id = b.id
```

The addition of a third joined table necessitates parentheses surrounding the original join in order to distinguish it from the additional join:

[image]

```sql
select *
from 
(
    a inner join b on a.id = b.id
) 
inner join c on a.id = c.id
```

Every successive addition of a table will then cause the existing joins to be nested within another level of parentheses:

[image]

```sql
select *
from 
(
    (
        a inner join b on a.id = b.id
    ) 
    inner join c on a.id = c.id
)
inner join d on a.id = d.id
```

Hence, in general:

```sql
select *
from 
(
    (
        (
            (
                table1 [inner/left/right] join table2 on [conditions]
            ) 
            [inner/left/right] join table3 on [conditions]
        )
        [inner/left/right] join table4 on [conditions]
    )
    ...
)
[inner/left/right] join tableN on [conditions]
```

There is a subtlety where `LEFT/RIGHT` joins are concerned, in that the order of nesting must maintain the direction of the join, for example:

[image]

```sql
select *
from 
(
    c left join b on c.id = b.id
) 
left join a on a.id = b.id
```

Could be permuted to:

```sql
select *
from 
c left join
(
    b left join a on b.id = a.id
)
on c.id = b.id
```

Comment: Regarding your final comment, you wrote `a left join something` and asserted that's not the same as `something left join a` - regrdless of brackets, is that not always the case in any db?

Comment: And the other thing I wondered; does access throw a fit if one just writes normal `a left join b left join c` queries? They work in the odbc/jet driver; I was wondering is it mandatory to parenthesize queries within access itself?

Comment: The parentheses pairings are part of Access' SQL dialect. Interesting about the JET ODBC driver not requiring them which I find hard to believe. Will check on that.

Comment: @CaiusJard You're quite right - it was a bad example - I have updated my answer with (hopefully) a better explanation of what I was trying to convey. And yes, MS Access will throw a syntax error without the parentheses surrounding each pair of tables.