# MS Access - missing operator in query expression

Tags: sql, .net, ms-access

I'm developing a .Net Platform app running against an Access Database.  The query is failing with the error:

> "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
>   'Repairs.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId Inner Join Device On
>   Repairs.DeviceId = Device.DeviceId Inner Join RepairType On
>   Repairs.RepairTypeId = RepairType.RepairTypeId'."

My Query is:

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerName, Device.Make, Device.Model, Device.Range, RepairType.RepairType, Repairs.DiscountPercent, RepairPrice.Price / 100 * (100-Repairs.DiscountPercent) As CustomerPrice 
From Repairs
Inner Join Customer On Repairs.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
Inner Join Device On Repairs.DeviceId = Device.DeviceId
Inner Join RepairType On Repairs.RepairTypeId = RepairType.RepairTypeId
```

I've tried wrapping each of the field names in square brackets, but to the same result

Comment: In Access you need parentheses when you have more than one join:

: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852571/842935

Comment: Use Access query builder to help get correct syntax.

Comment: You may wish to refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583206/7531598) for information on how to parenthesize joins in MS Access.