# Two IDs from same table in query - trying to get names for both IDs

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a couple of tables I'm trying to link together.  One table (`tblBrokeragePurchase`) has the information regarding a purchase order completed by a customer.  Within that table exists a BuyerID and a SellerID.  Both of those fields link to another table (`tblContacts`).  I'm wanting to output the full names of both the Buyer and the Seller, but Access is giving me some grief regarding the fields are being used in multiple aspects of my SQL statement.

So far, this is what I've got going on for myself:

```
SELECT [First Name] & " " & [Last Name] AS BuyerName, 
       [First Name] & " " & [Last Name] AS SellerName 
FROM   (tblBrokeragePurchase 
        LEFT JOIN tblContacts 
               ON ( tblBrokeragePurchase.SellerID = tblContacts.ID ) 
                  AND ( tblBrokeragePurchase.BuyerID = tblContacts.ID )) 
       INNER JOIN qryCityLookup 
               ON tblBrokeragePurchase.ID = qryCityLookup.ID 
WHERE  ( ( [BuyerID] = [ID] ) 
         AND ( [SellerID] = [ID] ) );
```

I'm decently sure it has to do with the `WHERE` statement.  The Buyer and the Seller will not be the same person (*generally?*).  So where do I need to fix up the `JOIN` or `WHERE` statement in my SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your query will be accessing two *separate* records from the `tblContacts` table for each record in your `tblBrokeragePurchase`, the `tblContacts` record will need to be referenced twice so that two separate records can be obtained by the query simultaneously.

In MS Access, the following should be valid SQL:

```sql
select
    b.[First Name] & " " & b.[Last Name] as BuyerName, 
    s.[First Name] & " " & s.[Last Name] as SellerName 
from
    (
        (
            tblBrokeragePurchase p left join tblContacts s on p.SellerID = s.ID
        ) 
        left join tblContacts b on p.BuyerID = b.ID
    )
    inner join qryCityLookup c on p.ID = c.ID 
where
    p.BuyerID  = [YourBuyerID] and 
    p.SellerID = [YourSellerID]
```

The additional parentheses are used as MS Access requires that each pair of joined tables/queries be surrounded by a separate set of parentheses - I describe the general structure [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583206/7531598).

Comment: I tried using this but it returns nothing.  I do have a record in ```tblBrokeragePurchase``` that has seller and buyer ID's listed.  Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.  I  used your exact code (copypasta) and changed ```YourBuyerID``` and ```YourSellerID``` to just be ```BuyerID``` and ```SellerID```.

Comment: `YourBuyerID` and `YourSellerID` should be changed to the values that you wish to filter for, e.g. `1` and `2` or be left as parameters to be supplied to the query. Alternatively, simply remove the entire `where` clause if you want to see the results for all `BuyerID` and `SellerID` combinations.

Answer (score 2):

You have to join to the contact table twice, and use alias to difference between boths

```
SELECT Buyer.[First Name] & " " & Buyer.[Last Name] AS BuyerName, 
       Seller.[First Name] & " " & Seller.[Last Name] AS SellerName 
FROM   (tblBrokeragePurchase 
        LEFT JOIN tblContacts as Seller
               ON ( tblBrokeragePurchase.SellerID = tblContacts.ID ) 
        LEFT JOIN tblContacts as Buyer
               ON ( tblBrokeragePurchase.BuyerID = tblContacts.ID ) 
       INNER JOIN qryCityLookup 
               ON tblBrokeragePurchase.ID = qryCityLookup.ID
```

Now if you are looking for a single ID then the WHERE clausule probably should be

```
WHERE  ( ( [BuyerID] = [ID] ) 
         OR ( [SellerID] = [ID] ) );
```

Comment: It's telling me there's a ```Syntax error in JOIN operation.```  Also, I am looking for TWO ID's.

Comment: Sorry I dont have an access available to check sintaxis, but Im sure is a parenthesis issue. Just add one table at the join each time

Comment: I messed around with this quite a bit and I can't seem to find any parentheses that are missing.