# How to fix syntax error in update query (missing operator)

Tags: sql, ms-access, jet

I'm attempting to update table progress_report by running the below query but when I run it I get the following: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

I've tried different variations of code but the one below is as correct as I believe it to be.

```
UPDATE progress_report AS per  
INNER JOIN cs_t AS cs ON per.person_id = cs.person_id
LEFT JOIN is_t AS ifaf ON cs.inst_id = ifaf.is_id
SET per.verif_status = cs.verif_status,
per.inst_id = cs.inst_id,
per.inst_type = ifaf.is_type
WHERE cs.yr = '2018'
```

The query runs fine without the Left Join but I need to join the is_t table to populate per.inst_type. So I'm assuming the error lies within the left join.

Comment: You may find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583206/7531598) useful in understanding where parentheses are required to surround joins in MS Access SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access has a special syntax when it comes to joins, unlike other dbms's. 
Parentheses are needed to enclose every join before the start of another join:

```
UPDATE (progress_report AS per  
INNER JOIN cs_t AS cs ON per.person_id = cs.person_id)
LEFT JOIN is_t AS ifaf ON cs.inst_id = ifaf.is_id
SET per.verif_status = cs.verif_status,
per.inst_id = cs.inst_id,
per.inst_type = ifaf.is_type
WHERE cs.yr = '2018'
```