# Query not running in MS Access.(Join and From Statements)

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT
    DL.DESCRIPTION
    , DL.ASSIGNEE
    , DL.LASTASSIGNEE
    , LU.BARCODE
    , FORMAT(D.ai_created, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH') AS [DATE AND HOUR CREATED]
    , SUM(DL.QUANTITY) AS [ITEM COUNT]
    , DL.MATERIAL_ID
    , (ACT.firstname & ' ' & ACT.lastname) AS [INDUCTORNAME]
    , D.ID AS [DLID]
FROM ANT_WMSDEMAND AS D
INNER JOIN ANT_WMSDEMANDLINE AS DL ON DL.DEMAND_ID = D.ID
INNER JOIN ANT_WMSLOADUNIT AS LU ON LU.ID = DL.LOADUNIT_ID
INNER JOIN ANT_ACTOR AS ACT on ACT.name = LEFT(DL.AI_CREATEDBY, 7)
WHERE 
    D.ai_created between CDATE('2019-12-15 06:00:00') ABD CDATE('2019-12-15 17:30:00')
    AND D.type = 'ORDER'
    AND D.STATE = 'ACTIVATED'
    AND D.REPORTER = 'PICKING_STATION'
GROUP BY 
    DL.DESCRIPTION, 
    DL.ASSIGNEE, 
    DL.LASTASSIGNEE, 
    LU.BARCODE, 
    FORMAT$(D.ai_created, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH'), 
    DL.MATERIAL_ID, 
    (ACT.firstname &' ' & ACT.lastname), 
    D.ID
ORDER BY FORMAT(D.ai_created, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH') ASC
```

The from statement and join need to have parenthesis but I haven't been able to figure out how and get it to work correctly. I tried doing it in the query builder and it still failed. Any ideas?

Comment: I removed the mysql tag, since the title states it is about ms-access.

Comment: What does *not running* mean? Are you getting an error, which one exactly? Please edit your question to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When more than one join exists, MS Access requires successive joins to be [surrounded by parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583206/7531598), hence your query should become:

```
SELECT
    DL.DESCRIPTION
    , DL.ASSIGNEE
    , DL.LASTASSIGNEE
    , LU.BARCODE
    , FORMAT(D.ai_created, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH') AS [DATE AND HOUR CREATED]
    , SUM(DL.QUANTITY) AS [ITEM COUNT]
    , DL.MATERIAL_ID
    , (ACT.firstname & ' ' & ACT.lastname) AS [INDUCTORNAME]
    , D.ID AS [DLID]
FROM 
    (
        (
            ANT_WMSDEMAND AS D INNER JOIN ANT_WMSDEMANDLINE AS DL ON
            DL.DEMAND_ID = D.ID
        )
        INNER JOIN ANT_WMSLOADUNIT AS LU ON 
        LU.ID = DL.LOADUNIT_ID
    )
    INNER JOIN ANT_ACTOR AS ACT ON 
    ACT.name = LEFT(DL.AI_CREATEDBY, 7)
WHERE 
    D.ai_created between #2019-12-15 06:00:00# AND #2019-12-15 17:30:00#
    AND D.type = 'ORDER'
    AND D.STATE = 'ACTIVATED'
    AND D.REPORTER = 'PICKING_STATION'
GROUP BY 
    DL.DESCRIPTION, 
    DL.ASSIGNEE, 
    DL.LASTASSIGNEE, 
    LU.BARCODE, 
    FORMAT(D.ai_created, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH'), 
    DL.MATERIAL_ID, 
    (ACT.firstname &' ' & ACT.lastname), 
    D.ID
ORDER BY 
    FORMAT(D.ai_created, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH') ASC
```

---

You also had a typo in your `between` statement:

```
D.ai_created between CDATE('2019-12-15 06:00:00') ABD CDATE('2019-12-15 17:30:00')
```

`ABD` should be `AND`.

---

The two `cdate` expressions could also be written as literal datetime values:

```
D.ai_created between #2019-12-15 06:00:00# AND #2019-12-15 17:30:00#
```