# How can I solve this Query Error in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have the next error of syntax in Access

```
SELECT Maestros.Nombre AS Maestro, Materias.Nombre AS Materia
FROM Maestros
INNER JOIN Maestros_Materias ON Maestros.id = Maestros_Materias.Maestro_id
INNER JOIN Materias ON Materias.id = Maestros_Materias.Materia_id
WHERE Maestros.id = 1;
```

I don't know what is the error here. Thanks for your answers

Comment: Please share the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Access, you need nested parentheses to handle multiple `JOIN`s.

This should do it:

```
SELECT Maestros.Nombre AS Maestro, Materias.Nombre AS Materia
FROM (Maestros
INNER JOIN Maestros_Materias ON Maestros.id = Maestros_Materias.Maestro_id) 
INNER JOIN Materias ON Materias.id = Maestros_Materias.Materia_id
WHERE Maestros.id = 1;
```

Comment: @CodeFluid You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583206/7531598) useful where the parentheses surrounding MS Access joins are concerned.